# Error shows when I use pygments with redcarpet on rails, how would I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have installed both gems, redcarpet and pygments.rb, and created a method and class in my application helper and called the method on @content on my show.html.erb, yet I get an error message.

code is on imgur
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vc6S.jpg

the error message shows when I replace Redcarpet::Render::HTML with HTMLwithPygments in the markdown method

if there are any more bits of the application you need to see please ask

error message as requested:

```
MentosError in Posts#show
Showing C:/Sites/mainsite/app/views/posts/show.html.erb where line #23 raised:
Failed to get header.
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:4:in `block_code'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:18:in `render'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:18:in `markdown'
app/views/posts/show.html.erb:23:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_erb__448466666_71119812'

Request
Parameters:
{"id"=>"sixth-post"}
```

application helper below:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  class HTMLwithPygments < Redcarpet::Render::HTM
    def block_code(code, language)
      Pygments.highlight(code, lexer: language)
    end
  end
  def markdown(content)
    renderer = HTMLwithPygments.new(hard_wrap: true, filter_html: true)
    options = {
      autolink: true,
      no_intra_emphasis: true,
      disable_indented_code_blocks: true,
      fenced_code_blocks: true,
      lax_html_blocks: true,
      strikethrough: true,
      superscript: true
    }
    Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, options).render(content).html_safe
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you please copy the error message into your question instead of linking an image. That helps future reader that have similar issues to find this question. Furthermore your images are unreadable on smaller screens

Comment: added error message for you

Comment: added app helper code